# Override Spring profile sam local start-lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli

I am using SAM to test my Lambda locally.

The Lambda has two spring profiles, one for local testing and one for production.

Currently, my Lambda is unable to pick up the test yml file.

```
sam-beta-cdk local start-lambda --env-vars env.json  --debug
```

The `env.json` file contains:

```
{
  "UniqueFunctionName": { "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE": "test" }
}
```

The Spring profile is labelled accordingly: `profile-test.yml`

Is the `--env-vars` the correct way to pass in JVM args?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your yml file should be named as `application-test.yml` instead of `profile-test.yml`.

Also, the `UniqueFunctionName` must be the logical id of your function in your sam template.